# storing user input in arrays for a log in site?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to make a mock up site that will allow you to create a username and password then for it to send that array of usernames and passwords over to a log in page where you will put in a username or password and it will go threw a process of checking weather it is wright or wrong and then what to do from there. what i have realized is that when i hit the button to send the information over it will not register on the other page. may you please help me find out what i screwed up on.

here is the code for where i create the username and password:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>
create account
</title>


<script>

function createLogIn() {
var usernameArray = document.getElementById("usernameMake").value;
var paswordArray = document.getElementById("pwordMake").value;

unArray.push("usernameArray");
pwArray.push("paswordArray");


localStorage.setItem("unArray", JSON.stringify([]));
localStorage.setItem("pwArray", JSON.stringify([]));

}
</script>


</head>

<body>

<form name = "makeLogIn">
  <p class="log_on">
    ENTER YOUR NEW USERNAME <input type="text" id="usernameMake"><br><br><br><br><br>
    ENTER YOUR NEW PASSWORD <input type="text" id="pwordMake">
    <input type="button" value="create it" id="Submit" onclick="createLogIn">
  </p>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

here is the code for logging in with that username and password:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
log on page
</title>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var count = 2;

function validate() {
    var un = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pw = document.getElementById("pword").value;
    var valid = false;

    var unArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("unArray"));
    var pwArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pwArray"));

    for (var i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
        valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        return false;
    }

    var t = " tries";

    if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

    if (count >= 1) {
        alert ("Invalid username and/or password. " +
               "You have " + count + t + " left.");
        document.myform.username.value = "";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
        count --;
    }

    else {
        alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
        document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        document.myform.username.disabled = true;
        document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }

}
</script>

    <style>

    p.log_on{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 20px;
}
</style>





</head>


<body>

<form name = "myform">
  <p class="log_on">
    ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" id="username"><br><br><br><br><br>
    ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" id="pword">
    <input type="button" value="Check In" id="Submit" onclick="validate()">
  </p>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: are u getting any errors or something in console?

Comment: no. it just says that i put in a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

In function for create login you:

1. You use undefined arrays `unArray` and `pwArray`
2. You push to this arrays string but not value of variables
3. You save to local storage empty array.

Comment: can you give me the changed code. i am new to JavaScript and cant seam to do it myself.

Comment: @samtam try change your code self. I wrote about your errors.